# How to find the rank of the set of vectors $\{(5,x), x\in \mathbb R\}$, $S \subset \mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Let $S$ be the set of column vectors such that $\{(5,x), x\in \mathbb R\}$  and $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

What will be the rank of $S$ in this case?

Also, what will be the basis and how many basis will we have?

Comment: The set of vectors of the form $\left\{\begin{bmatrix}5\\x\end{bmatrix}~:~x\in\Bbb R\right\}$  do not form a vector space (*e.g. the zero vector is not included*).  That being said, if you were to ignore that, you could choose to write any element as $\begin{bmatrix}5\\0\end{bmatrix}+x\cdot \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ for some value of $x\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: My bad. I didn't mention that $S \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Also, vector (1,0) does not belong to $S$, so how are you using that?

Comment: Again, $S$ is merely a sub**set** and is *not* a sub**space** of $\Bbb R^2$.  We normally reserve words like rank and basis to be used only for sub*spaces* and they are meaningless for subsets.  If you were to extend the definition for subsets as well to refer to the homogeneous parts, your subset *resembles* the subspace of rank $1$ with basis $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ which has then been shifted by $\begin{bmatrix}5\\0\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean by $rank(S)$ the dimension of $span(S)$.

First of all 
$$span(S) \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \Rightarrow dim(S) \leq 2$$

Consider $u = \begin{pmatrix}5 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $v = \begin{pmatrix}5 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$:
$$u,v \in S \mbox{ and } rank\begin{pmatrix}5  & 5 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = 2 \Rightarrow rank(S) = 2$$

Concerning possible bases of $span(S)$ belonging to $S$:

Just choose $u = \begin{pmatrix}5 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $v_x = \begin{pmatrix}5 \\ x \end{pmatrix}$ with $x \neq 0$.